# How do I pass a parameter to a scoped service in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have some .Net code that I need to migrate to .NET 5. Specifically, I'm registering a number of services. I've migrated most of the services, except, I'm stuck on those that need to have a parameter passed. My legacy code looks like this:

```
private void RegisterItem<T>(ContainerBuilder builder) where T : Item
{
  builder
    .RegisterType<StoreItem<T>>()
    .As<IItem<T>>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IStore>(nameof(MyContext)))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
  ;
}
```

I was trying to modify the code above to use:

```
services.AddScoped<IItem<T>, StoreItem<T>>();
```

However, this does not pass in the parameter that was set in the original implementation. My question is, how do I pass a parameter to a scoped service in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: What issue are you seeing?

Comment: Can you add the code that demonstrates how you resolve `IItem<T>`? Can you also explain what this `IStore` is for type of value? Where is it coming from? Is it an application constant? Is it loaded once from the database? Does it change per request?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add them as a parameter to your constructor, and they will be resolved by the dependency injection engine:

```cs
public StoreItem(IStore store)
{
   ...
}
```

Note that `IStore` must be registered as well:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IStore, MyStore>();
```